# How to keep content of oracle view v$sql more time?

Tags: oracle, performance

I try to analyse the cost of sql statement according v$sql result in Oracle database. But view's content is timing cleared.

How should I do to keep content of v$sql more time? Thanks.

Comment: Use  `dba_hist_sqltext`

Answer (score 1):

You need to query DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT instead.
But be careful this view is part of the oracle diagnostic pack, you need to have a diagnostic pack license to query it.